# Loop not terminating when joining on all other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

First of all I searched the answer forever. 
I've been trying to join all of my Threads this way:

```
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
try {
    for (Thread t : threads)
    if(t!=Thread.currentThread())
        t.join(5*1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop? I can see the threads are ending when I debug so what's up?

I also tried:

```
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
try {
    for (Thread t : threads)
    if(!t.toString().contains("main") || !t.toString().contains("system"))
        t.join(5*1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and I get the same results. help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What are the threads doing? Looks to me it's more likely your program ends in a deadlock...

Comment: They are simulating some warfare :>
I can tell it works perfectly (and all threads die) if I put the code in notes (the program terminates cleanly)

Comment: could you just use an executor service? also why force the extra operation in 5*1000 when 5000 will do. Finally, are you supposed to return anything, what type of thread is it (Callable/runnable/just plain thread)? why not use a runnable? More code would be helpful.thanks

Comment: Sadly I can't use an ExecutorService because there's much going in the background (threads fire other threads, interrupt each other, etc...)
what did you mean @user2864740 I thought Set is a type of collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for threads to die that are part of the JVM, but you incorrectly specified your logic.  All threads will fit the condition "doesn't contain main or doesn't contain system", unless it somehow contains both words.  Try using `&&` instead:

```
if(!t.toString().contains("main") && !t.toString().contains("system"))
```

Using `&&`, my process exists quickly.

If you're waiting for threads to die, then maintain your own list of threads that your program starts, and wait for them to die.  Don't obtain a list from `Thread.getAllStackTraces`, because that will contain other threads that you didn't start and won't die first.

Comment: @user2864740 There is the "main" `Thread` itself and there are other `Thread`s that the JVM starts and are picked up by `Thread.getAllStackTraces`, but they remain running as long as the JVM does, AFAIK.  These are the "system" threads that are filtered out by the `if` condition.

Comment: @user2864740 because when I used the
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
it also includes main and system threads.